# Writing multiple NCDF4 files

Tags: r

I am trying to write multiple NCDF4 file with R. I have a huge amount of files to read in analysis and output to new NCDF4 files.
I have the code below for creating and writing to an individual NCDF4 file. This code works well to create and write to a file.
I need a bit of code to replace    ncfname<-"ABC123.nc” and to loop thus producing one NCDF4 new file for every file analysed. When I try using a loop as I would in R generally, if fails. It appears that the NCDF4 package wants to see “nc” extension.
My code is below. Can anyone help on this?

```
#####Write NCDF4 files#############################################
###################################################################

tunits<-"days since 1600-01-01 00:00:00"

#Define dimensions
##################################################################
londim<-ncdim_def("Lon","degrees_east",as.double(Lon))
latdim<-ncdim_def("Lat", "degrees_north",as.double(Lat))
timedim<-ncdim_def("time",tunits,as.double(time))

#Define variables
##################################################################
fillvalue<-(-1e32)

dlname<-"2 meter air temperature"
dlname2<-" 2 meter max air temperature"

 tmp_def<-ncvar_def("Data1","deg_C",
  list(londim,latdim,timedim),fillvalue,dlname,prec = "double")
tmp_def2<-ncvar_def("Data2","deg_C", 
 list(londim,latdim,timedim),fillvalue,dlname2,prec = "double")

#Create Ncdf4 file and  put arrays 
##################################################################
ncfname<-"ABC123.nc"

ncout<-nc_create(ncfname,list(tmp_def,tmp_def2),force_v4=T)

#Put variables
#################################################################

ncvar_put(ncout,tmp_def,Data2,start=NA,count = NA )
ncvar_put(ncout,tmp_def2,Data1, start= NA,count = NA )


ncatt_put(ncout,"Lon","axis","X")
ncatt_put(ncout, "Lat", "axis", "Y")
ncatt_put(ncout, "time","axis", "T")

#################################################
title<-c( 1:2 )
names(title)<-c("jack","jill")
title<-as.data.frame(title)
################################################

# attributes # the 0 designates the attribute as global 
###########################################################
ncatt_put(ncout,0,"Make_NCDF4_File",1, prec="int")
ncatt_put(ncout,0,"XXXXXX",1,prec="short")
ncatt_put(ncout,0,"AR000087828",1, prec="short")
ncatt_put(ncout,0,"description","this is the script to write NCDF4files")


#Close file and write date to disk
##########################################################
nc_close(ncout)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looping through data and creating a netCDF4 file each iteration will work so long as your loop is set up correctly. First and foremost, your loop syntax needs to be correct. Your example does not have your loop in it so I cannot comment on it directly. Secondly, you'll have to get different strings to name your netCDF file, as you have pointed out. You can use something like this

```
ncfname <- sprintf('ABC%03d.nc', i)
```

if we assume `i` is your loop iterator. Of course, you can use any number of other variables to help `sprintf` build a file name. Just be aware of the proper formatting syntax. The nice thing about `sprintf` is that you have lots of format control and can easily include things like the '.nc' extension in the format string so it is included in every file name. `paste` would be another useful function to build the file name as well if that works better for you.

Lastly, be conscious of where you loop goes in your script. What I mean by this is do not have variables set over and over again if they do not have to be. In your case, any `ncdf4` package function (e.g., `ncdim_def`) that does not depend on or create `ncfname` can be placed outside the loop and be used to build each netCDF file. In general, dimension and variable objects can be defined outside loops when each file is similar except for the actual data input by `ncvar_put`.

Comment: Thank you nawendt

Comment: I will work on this and hopefully be back to you to confirm sucess

Comment: Thank you nawendt. That bit of code works perfectly. I just have to solve why its not looping. But that a different problem . Ian

Comment: Nawendt. i have tried everything I know to get the loop right and i can only one output file. My whole analysis loop is about 400 line long, so far to big to put up here. Can you give me a simple loop example for this purpose, that prehsaps i can adjust for my needs

Comment: Since it might be a simple fix, could you tell me what the error message is with the loop? Or at least what is not working within the loop?

Comment: Thank you Nawendt.

Comment: There is no error message. The first file is created and all date wrote to it. But only the first file. i am currently working with a test directory of 3 input file expecting 3 output files. But i only get the first

Comment: If you need more help with R for loops, there is lots of documentation on that out there. For your use case, it sounds to me like you want to iterate over the files to read in for analysis. In that case you can use a function like `list.files` to get the file locations in a character vector to loop over. Only other issue I can think of happening here is that you call your script with `source` in the loop and then it just does the same thing three times. The for loop has to be in the script itself.

Comment: Thanks you Nawendt Ian